# Does uniform convergence imply convergence of the integrals?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space. Take a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in
>  \mathbb N}$ of real-valued measurable **bounded** functions. Suppose $f_n \to f$
>   uniformly on $X$ and suppose that $\mu(X)<+\infty$. Then $$ \int_X f_n
>  d\mu \to \int_Xf d\mu $$ when $n \to +\infty$.

This exercise is taken from Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*, chapter 1. I do not understand where I should use the hypothesis of boundedness of the functions. Indeed, 
$$
\left \vert \int_X f-f_n d\mu \right\vert \le \int_X \vert f_n - f \vert d\mu \le \int_X \varepsilon d\mu = \varepsilon \mu(X)   
$$
for $n$ sufficiently big.

Where do I use the boundedness of the functions? Do I need it in order to say $\vert \int_X f_n-f d\mu\vert \le \int \vert f-f_n \vert d\mu$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boundedness of the maps and finiteness of the measure space are used to be sure that $\int_Xf_nd\mu$ and $\int_Xfd\mu$ are real numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. So my proof is coorect, provided I say: "All these quantities are finite because $f_n$ (hence $f$ which is their uniform limit) are bounded". Thanks a lot for your kind and fast help.

Comment: Yes. Actually, it's a sufficient condition to assume boundedness. For example, integrability of all these functions is enough.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thanks, I just saw your answer. I've a related question: say a sequence of uniformly bounded functions $f_n$ converges uniformly to zero on an infinite measure, measure space $X$. Does this necessarily mean $\int_{X} f_n d\mu \to 0?$

Comment: @LearningMath Take $f_n=n^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}$ on the positive real line.

Answer (score 2):

If the functions are not bounded, you may not be able to consider the absolute value of the difference. you might end up with infinity-infinity which is undefined.